# i can't download the pretrained model of uunet, why?

Tags: github, deep-learning, medical-imaging

the error tells me that the url is not found, but i just do as the readme said, have something changed ?
the github: https://github.com/MIC-DKFZ/nnUNet/tree/nnunetv1?tab=readme-ov-file#installation
error: requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://zenodo.org/record/8189234/files/nnUNet_FZJ_v2.zip?download=1

i can run this pretrained model

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: FYI I was able to download the data using your link.  Something must be wrong with the internet on your end.

Comment: sorry, i‘m wrong, i'll give more detail again. i download the model as the readme said, the coda is 'pip install git+https://github.com/MIC-DKFZ/nnUNet.git@nnunetv1', then i successfully use the code "nnUNet_print_available_pretrained_models" to print all the pretained model, but when i try to install a pretrained model use "nnUNet_download_pretrained_model Task029_LiTS" as the readme said, the error told that "requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://zenodo.org/record/4003545/files/Task029_LITS.zip?download=1", i don't know why